# Disappearing Text on Google Chrome - google web fonts?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, jscript

Website: www.ibodyguardsdirect.com

Issue - text missing on first load.  Appears on refresh.

Sources checked - seems related to Google Fonts not loading first time round - which is weird considering Google Chrome and Google Fonts are both the same company.

Tried this in header - didn't work

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     if($.browser.chrome)
         $("head").append('<style>/* Web Fonts*/ @font-face 
  {    font-family: "webfont"; src: url("webfont.eot");    font-weight: normal;    font-style: normal; }}</style>');
 });
```

Tried this in the CSS stylesheet - didnt work

```
  body
      {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
      -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
      }

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix{
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Ive also been through all these blogs
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zID6uQQfKH8
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-doesnt-display-content-text-on-chrome?replies=16#post-5283430
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246875

Still not fixed

Does anyone know how to sort this issue?

Comment: In the newest version of google canary it is fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disappearing Text on Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530860/disappearing-text-on-google-chrome)

Comment: @Daan - yes but we cannot ask every visitor to update their Chrome so need a better fix

Comment: @brasofilo - yes I got a message that the other post lacked enough details so I edited it, but it never got republished so I created a new post here.

Answer (score 0):

The `.eot` which you use as `webfont.eot` is type of font that can be derived from a regular font, allowing small files and legal use of high-quality fonts.

Usage is restricted by the file being tied to the website, and it is supported only by `Internet Explorer`, version 8.0 and up.

Try testing by switching to `.woff` format of the font (you can easily convert `.eot` font into `.woff` online).